# unable to locate the element in selenium WebDriver using C#

Tags: javascript, selenium, button, webdriver, findelement

how to find element for this below html tag ?

I am getting

> exception: no such element: Unable to locate element:
>
> {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='divMain']/div/app-train-list/div[2]/app-modify-search/p-confirmdialog/div/div/div[3]/html/body/app-root/app-home/div[3]/div/app-train-list/div[2]/app-modify-search/p-confirmdialog/div/div/div[3]/button"}

```
IWebElement berthOK = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='divMain']/div/app-train-list/div[2]/app-modify-search/p-confirmdialog/div/div/div[3]/html/body/app-root/app-home/div[3]/div/app-train-list/div[2]/app-modify-search/p-confirmdialog/div/div/div[3]/button"));
if (berthOK.Displayed)  //*[@id='divMain']/div/app-train-list/div[2]/app-modify-search/p-confirmdialog/div/div/div[3]
berthOK.Click();
```

Comment: That xpath looks absolute, can you share the HTML for that button ? or if URL is there that'd be help too.

Comment: I have commented the Relative Xpath aswel below that absolute path.   html is  ```  <div class="ui-dialog-footer ui-widget-content ng-tns-c57-72 ng-star-inserted" style=""><button type="button" pbutton="" class="ng-tns-c57-72 ui-confirmdialog-acceptbutton ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-left ng-star-inserted"><span aria-hidden="true" class="ui-button-icon-left ui-clickable pi pi-check"></span><span class="ui-button-text ui-clickable">OK</span></button><!----><!----></div>                                                  ```

Comment: Is it `OK` button that you wanna click on ?

Comment: yes, OK-submit button

Comment: try it out the below solution

Comment: Can you share Page URL in that case  ?

Comment: url is https://www.irctc.co.in/nget/booking/train-list, in that pop-up message box comes only if we select Lower berth

Comment: When I select the lower berth, I do not see any pop-message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234208/discussion-between-aishwarya-mohan-and-cruisepandey).

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's `OK` button that you wanna click.

```
IWebElement berthOK = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[text()='OK']/.."));
if(berthOK.Displayed)
berthOK.Click();
```

or for more reliability make sure to use **WebDriverWait** :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//span[text()='OK']/.."))).Click();
```

Comment: no again getting the same error, unable to find element

Comment: ExpectedConditions is obsolete so again getting errors

Comment: Is it also or irctc ? if yes then let me know, where is it ?

Comment: yes, it is also irctc.... once you select the quota as senior citizen/ lower berth, that pop up message comes and click on search...again inside that pop up displays

Comment: I could find that `OK` button. what is the error when you use this code `new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//span[text()='OK']/.."))).Click();` - ExpectedConditions is not obsolete